# Refresh Partial View after submitting a form in it's parent View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am new to using Partial Views so I am a little confused here.

I am submitting a form in a View that triggers this ActionResult:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNote(string comment)
    {
            using (var entity = new Entities())
            {
                var orderId = TempData["OrderId"].ToString();
                var atp = User.Identity.Name;
                entity.uspAddOrderNote(orderId, atp, comment);
            }
        return PartialView("WipOrders");
    }
```

I would only like to refresh the partial view `WipOrders` (which is within the View that's submitting the form) once the form is submitted, but it is either only letting me return the full view or, in the case of what is written above, returning the url `~/AddNote`.

I was trying to change the form to ajax in the hopes that it would work, but I am having some trouble:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNote", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add A Note</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="orderId" name="orderId"/>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Is it possible to only refresh the Partial View once this is submitted?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your using `Ajax.BeginForm()` but have not specified any of the options such as `UpdateTargetId`

Comment: I tried to specify the target id, but the actionresult is still navigating to `/AddNote`, which does not exist. Not sure why it isn't just refreshing the Partial View

Comment: That means its making a normal submit - you need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right. You need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`. You can install it by running this command below in Nuget Package Manager then include the script.

`Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`